# Using struct arrays and files to pass value through functions

Tags: c, arrays

I'm reading input data from a file and storing it in a struct array.

I'm doing this successfully, and am able to store the data and to print it using the struct array. just to confirm it was definitely stored.

Now I'm prompting the user to enter a name entered in the file to choose the person. The point of this is to divide the money they have given over the largest available coins (e.g. 80 cents is a 50 cent coin, a 20 cent coin and a 10 cent coin.) After choosing the person I have tried storing the chosen line into another struct array but am having trouble doing so.

```
{
    int choice,I;
    char search[SIZE];
    printf("1. Enter Name\n");
    printf("2. Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if(choice == 1)
    {
        printf("Please enter the name: ");
        scanf(" %s", &search);

        for(i=0; i < RECIPIENT; i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(search, all[i].allname)==0)
            {
                input[].fcents = all[i].coins;
                strcpy(input[].name, all[i].allname);
                printf("%s %d\n", input[].name, input[].fcents);
            }
        }
        if(strcmp(search, all[i].allname)!=0)
        {
            printf("Name is not in system");
        }
    }
    return(choice);
}
```

This is my current menu function. This works and can display the name correctly if I swap the printf variables for the `all[]` array. My inability to give the `input[]` array is preventing me to proceed further. I have other functions that rely on this successful array assignments. Where am I going wrong with assigning my variables?

Comment: Hello. Can you update your post with the function prototype? Thx

Comment: As @Jean-MarcVolle already wrote, the prototype of the function is required and, if it is not the main, you should also include a `main()` application able to reproduce your issue. Last but not least, what do you mean when you write _"but am having trouble doing so"_? What happens exactly? Do you have a crash? Do you get wrong results? Which results?